# What is the limit behavior of this functions of two variables?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have a function of two variables with different limits depending on how they're approached.
$$f\left(c,d\right)\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-d}^{d}\left(e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}-e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}+cx^{3}}\right)dx$$

Clearly,
$$\lim_{d\rightarrow\infty} f\left(c,d\right)=\infty;c\neq0$$
but
$$f\left(c=0,d\right)=0$$ for all d

My question is, is there some functional relationship $c(d)$ where $c\rightarrow0$ as $d\rightarrow\infty$ (like for example, $c\propto1/d^{3}$ ) that would make $$\lim_{d\rightarrow\infty} f\left(c(d),d\right)$$ come out finite and non-zero?

Comment: Factorization by $e^{-x^2/2}$, gives a second factor that can be expanded into a Taylor series (with $c \to 0$): whose dominant term is $cx^3$. The question now is whether you are looking for a fully rigorous answer or an idea about the kind of function $c(d)$... for example $c(d)=d$.

Comment: @JeanMarie  What I'd specifically ultimately like to know is what function c(d) would make f finite and non-zero as d->inf

Comment: @JeanMarie What I'm ultimately getting at is finding the pdf that maximizes entropy given the 0th through 3rd order moments.  But that requires figuring this out.

Comment: Following your last comment, this reminds me of [Gram-Charlier expansion](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/154264174.pdf) but maybe I am wrong...

Comment: @JeanMarie  Well, I see a tangential relationship, but I'm not seeing how that helps me solve this problem.